# Django smtp sendmail not working after deployment

Tags: python, django, deployment, smtp, web-development-server

I created a contact form for my django app that sends straight to my email after the user completes it.

It is working when I run it on my local host but after deployment it take me to an error server error (500)

```
////settings.py////

import os 

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

** NOTE I ALSO TRIED THIS WITH THE ACTUAL EMAILS INSTEAD OF ENV VARIABLES **

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False


///// views.py ////

def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('full-name'). 
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        data = {
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "subject": subject,
            "message": message,
        }

        message = '''
        New message: {}

        From: {}

        '''.format(data['message'], data['email'])
        send_mail(data["subject"], message, '', ['svalaiemusic@gmail.com'])
    return render(request, "contact.html", {})
```

Comment: what does the stack trace (from your prod server) say?

Comment: @AdamSmooch sorry I'm a new developer.  Im not sure how to access my stack trace.  Im running on ubuntu 20

Comment: That's what you'll need if you hope to debug - wherever you start your [python] server, stack trace should be nearby 

Comment: If you are running Django behind a webserver like Apache or Nginx, the Django logs may be found in the webserver's error logs.

Comment: Hello @shayanvalaie can you provide full error by setting your DEBUG to True